# How do I get my Fn key to work on a Thinkpad T430s?

Tags: keyboard-layout, thinkpad, acpi

I have installed 16.04 on t430s laptop. FN key is not working, which means that none of the `FN` key-combos work. (e.g. `FN+F8` should decrese screen brightness.

running `xev` in terminal shows that nothing registers when I pres `FN`. `FN` keycombo only registers the normal Fkey (e.g. `FN` + `F8` shows the same keyevent in xev as `F8`does.

`dmesg | grep thin` returns this:

```
[   15.600090] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
[   15.600093] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[   15.600094] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS G7ET60WW (2.02 ), EC unknown
[   15.600096] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T430s, model 2356LNG
[   15.608778] thinkpad_acpi: detected a 16-level brightness capable ThinkPad
[   15.608878] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[   15.608895] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[   15.608896] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[   15.610449] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked
[   15.611064] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_wwan_sw: radio is unblocked
[   15.614049] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading [   15.600090] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
[   15.600093] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[   15.600094] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS G7ET60WW (2.02 ), EC unknown
[   15.600096] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T430s, model 2356LNG
[   15.608778] thinkpad_acpi: detected a 16-level brightness capable ThinkPad
[   15.608878] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[   15.608895] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[   15.608896] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[   15.610449] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked
[   15.611064] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_wwan_sw: radio is unblocked
[   15.614049] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[   15.623189] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input8
[ 4532.846826] thinkpad_acpi: deprecated sysfs attribute: access by process with PID 4434
[ 4532.846832] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: sysfs attribute hotkey_enable is deprecated and will be removed. Hotkey reporting is always enabled
[ 4665.791698] thinkpad_acpi: deprecated sysfs attribute: access by process with PID 4491
[ 4665.791706] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: sysfs attribute bluetooth_enable is deprecated and will be removed. Please switch to generic rfkill before year 2010native one
[   15.623189] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input8
[ 4532.846826] thinkpad_acpi: deprecated sysfs attribute: access by process with PID 4434
[ 4532.846832] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: sysfs attribute hotkey_enable is deprecated and will be removed. Hotkey reporting is always enabled
[ 4665.791698] thinkpad_acpi: deprecated sysfs attribute: access by process with PID 4491
[ 4665.791706] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: sysfs attribute bluetooth_enable is deprecated and will be removed. Please switch to generic rfkill before year 2010
```

When I venture down to `/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi` and do a `ls -l hotkey_* | cut -d' ' -f9` I get 9 files back:

```
hotkey_all_mask
hotkey_bios_enabled
hotkey_bios_mask
hotkey_enable
hotkey_mask
hotkey_poll_freq
hotkey_radio_sw
hotkey_recommended_mask
hotkey_source_mask
```

Which have theese values (`cat hotkey*`)

```
0x07fffffb
0
0x00000808
1
0x078c7ffb
10
1
0x078c7ffb
0x00000000
```

So basically - I have no idea how to get FN keys working. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It apears my problem must have been due to a faulty / dead FN key. A hardware issue that is.

My 'solutoin': To swap ctrl and FN via the relevant bios option. Then I was without a left ctrl key. So I swapped left ctrl with caps lock.

the xmapmod for this is availble via google, but for the sake of posterity the process is:

First Backup your current xmodmap: `xmodmap -pke > Xmodmap_orig`. The create a copy og the existing xmodmap: `xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap`. Now edit this file: `vim .Xmodmap` and paste the following at the bottom of the file

```
! Switch caps lock and (left) control
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

Save and source the modified xmodmap: `xmodmap .Xmodmap`

p.s I you are new to vim, the maybe choose `nano` instead.